# How do I remove the ellipses from Firefox's address bar history?

Tags: firefox

When I begin to type a link into Firefox's address bar, a menu of suggestions appears:
[image]

I usually tab through these to get to the link I want, so that I don't have to type out the entire link. Recently though, I have to press tab twice to get between every address, because it first tabs to these ellipses which offer to open a menu.

How do I disable this menu, so that I can continue to tab through the list of suggested addresses more quickly?

Comment: Can't you use the up and down arrows to navigate through that list?

Comment: This is off-topic here. It might be on-topic on [su] and perhaps on other sites, like [apple.se], [ubuntu.se], [unix.se].